# Iptables block all except when from localhost?

Tags: webserver, iptables

I'm trying to set up my server to block all incoming traffic except for SSH from anywhere, and HTTP when from localhost (so that I have to tunnel in to use the webserver).

Here are my rules, as generated by `iptables-save`.

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [10:536]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [11:1140]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 80 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j DROP
COMMIT
```

SSH works fine, but `wget localhost` still doesn't work.

How come?

Comment: Don't forget to accept packets in the direction from webserver to your client (wget) - ACCEPT ESTABLISHED for --sport 80.

Comment: @Messa I've updated my post to reflect your change, and also removed `-A OUTPUT -j DROP`.  I still can't wget localhost, and also I've noticed I can't ping the outside world.

Comment: Is your web server running? :) You can check with `nestat -ntpl`

Comment: Also keep in mind that `localhost` might translate to IPv6 address so don't forget to set up ip6tables too.

Comment: You couldn't ping outside world because the ping went out OK, but the pong (ping response :)) was dropped when going through INPUT filter because it matched no rule until the DROP. If you set default or last rule DROP then you should not forget to accept things like ICMP (pings etc.).

Comment: Start with `-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT`. Read some manual to see what ICMP types exactly you want to accept (there is more than just ping).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
$ cat rules
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Mon Aug 25 15:06:42 2014
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j DROP
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Aug 25 15:06:42 2014
$ sudo iptables-apply rules
Applying new iptables rules from 'rules'... done.
Can you establish NEW connections to the machine? (y/N) y
... then my job is done. See you next time.
$ curl http://127.0.0.1/
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
```

Comment: That works for me also!  ...kinda.  I still can't send traffic out from the machine.  Can't ping, or resolve names, or telnet 31.55.163.155 80 (google.com).  I don't really understand why since your script doesn't block anything outgoing (yes, I flushed before applying).

Comment: You have to unblock not just the requests, but also the responses :) See my last comment to your question.

Comment: Thanks, working now.  To anyone who Googled their way here in the future: http://serverfault.com/questions/429400/iptables-rule-to-allow-all-outbound-locally-originating-traffic